# Задача на разности

Tags: c++

Всем привет ! Есть такая задача она проходит 50%. Помогите пожалуйста найти мою ошибку ,ни как не могу найти ! Вот задача :

Целое число A содержит не более 1000 десятичных цифр. Обозначим через B и C соответственно максимальное и минимальное из чисел, составленных из цифр A. Числа B и С должны иметь тот же знак, что и A. Найдите разность между B и C.

Входные данные
В единственной строке находится десятичная запись числа A.
Выходные данные
В одной строке искомая разностью.

Пример входных данных

```
418
```

Пример выходных данных

```
693
```

Пример входных данных

```
-1032
```

Пример выходных данных

```
2187
```

Пример входных данных

```
8814
```

Пример выходных данных

```
7353
```

Мой код :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define MAXN 200010

using namespace std;

long long sto_int(string s)
{
    stringstream ss(s);
    long long n;
    ss >> n;
    return n;
}
bool sorthus(char i, char j)
{
    return (i > j);
}

int main()
{
    string cis, cis2, cis3;
    char temp;
    cin >> cis;
    cis3 = cis;
    sort(cis3.begin(), cis3.end());
    long long cnt = 0;

    for (long long i = 0; i < cis3.size(); i++)
    {
        if (cis3[i] == '0')cnt++;
    }

    if (cis3[0] == '-')
    {
        if (cis3[1] == '0')
        {
            swap(cis3[1], cis3[1 + cnt]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (cis3[0] == '0')
        {
            swap(cis3[0], cis3[0 + cnt]);
        }
    }

    cis2 = cis3;

    if (cis[0] == '-')
    {
        sort(cis2.begin() + 1, cis2.end(), sorthus);
    }
    else
    {
        sort(cis2.begin(), cis2.end(), sorthus);
    }

    long long cis22 = sto_int(cis2);
    long long cis33 = sto_int(cis3);

    if (cis22 < 0)cout << cis33 - cis22 << endl;
    else cout << cis22 - cis33 << endl;

    cout << cis33 << " " << cis22 << endl;
    cout << cis3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы всерьез рассчитываете на то, что типа `long long` хватит для 1000-значного числа?... И еще - зачем изобретать велосипед `sto_int` при наличии стандартной `stoll`?

Comment: то есть здесь длинная арифметика ?

Comment: Еще какая длинная :)

Comment: ок попробую исправить @Harry ,спасибо !

Comment: @Harry написал с помощью библиотеки , но показывает ошибка компиляции на сайте ,где это библиотека раньше работала. А вот на ideone спокойно показала http://ideone.com/P83Tby .

Comment: У вас там - где сдавать - точно boost можно использовать?..

Comment: да можно @Harry. Были задачи где сдавал их с помощью буста